# PHP Klein Uncaught Error: Wrong Parameters

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a PHP REST API using Klein as the routing library. Trying to test one of the get routes throw the exception below:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Klein\Exceptions\UnhandledException([string 
$message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]) in C:\DA4NA4\Web\task- 
scheduler\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php:954
Stack trace:
#0 C:\DA4NA4\Web\task-scheduler\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php(954): Exception- 
&gt;__construct('SQLSTATE[HY000]...', 'HY000', Object(PDOException))
#1 C:\DA4NA4\Web\task-scheduler\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php(645): Klein\Klein- 
&gt;error(Object(PDOException))
#2 C:\DA4NA4\Web\task-scheduler\public\index.php(20): Klein\Klein-&gt;dispatch()
#3 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\DA4NA4\Web\task-scheduler\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Klein.php</b> on line 
<b>954</b><br />
```

**My routes file contained the following codes**:

```
<?PHP 
require_once '../bootstrap.php';

use Api\Controllers\UserController;

$users = new UserController();

/**
 * user routes
 */

//1. get user
$klein->respond('GET', '/api/users/[:username]', function($request){
    global $users;
    return $users->getUser($request->username);
});


//dispatch routes
$klein->dispatch();
```

**And finally, here's the method from the UserController Class:**

```
public function getUser(string $username){
        /**
         * process requests for a username
         * @param string $username
         */

        /**
         * set http headers
         */
        \header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
        \header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
        \header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        \header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600');
        

        /**
         * sanitize username
         */
        $username = \test_input($username);

        if(empty($username)){
            throw new Exception('Provide username');
        }

        $user = $this->model->getOne($username);

        if($user){
            /**
             * set http status code
             * 200 - successfull
             */
            \http_response_code(200);

            /**
             * encode the user records in json format
             * send encode records to user
             */
            echo \json_encode(['status'=>true, 'message'=>$user]);
        }
    }
```

What I'm possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that exception code is expected to be integer (long in the stacktrace), but PDOException returns strings as exception codes.

There is an open issue about this problem since 2015: https://github.com/klein/klein.php/issues/298

A bigger problem is that you are using library which has been unmaintained for 4 years (since February 2017). My advice is to look for alternative to Klein router.